# DOS batch file - Display popup message with two choices

Tags: windows, popup, dos, multiple-choice

Using a DOS batch file I'd like to display a popup window in XP and Windows 7  where I display a message and give the user the choice to press one of two buttons - one would stop the DOS batch file, while the other button would allow it to continue. 
Any hint on what dos batch command/pgm I may use?

Answer (score 2):

The following WSH/VBscript snippet prompts the user to click yes/no, after which you can base logic on the response:

```
'enter this text into ask.vbs
dim input
input = MsgBox ("Do you want to continue?", 4)
'wscript.echo input

If input = 7 Then
   'answer was no
End If

If input = 6 Then
   'answer was yes
End If
```

Then in your batch file, call `wscript ask.vbs`.

However, I recommend staying in pure console for this task if you can, as `choice` and `set` can handle this nicely as Anders suggests.  `pause` works very well too, and that's usually what I use for a binary choice like yours because it's the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

To display an actual window you would have to call something external, a .exe or a Windows Scripting Host [script](http://ss64.com/vb/popup.html).

If you want to stay in pure batch, `echo` the choices and use [`SET /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to wait for input from the user. (To support DOS and Win9x you would have to use `choice` and not `set` on those systems)